# GCMNetworkManager OneOffTask execution window

Tags: android, gcm-network-manager

What happens to a OneOffTask if it requires network to be connected but the phone never gets network connectivity during the execution window?
How can this situation be handled or does GCMNetworkManager automatically handle it by re-scheduling the task?

Answer (score 0):

As described in the documentation for [Task.Builder](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/Task.Builder.html#setRequiredNetwork(int)),

> If the specified network is unavailable your task will not be executed until it becomes available.

This sounds pretty vague, but in practice `GcmNetworkManager` will probably postpone the task execution and run it once the network becomes available.